# how to show dynamically created div html in another div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html there are multiple div which is created dynamically with comman class and one div is for show all html or data of that div those are dynamically created.

 by the clicking on show button i have to show all data of dynamically created div with jQuery but cundition is only that div data or html should show of thair checkbox is checked.
 how to do with jQuery.

for example there are three div so i checked first div and third div so on the button click i have to show in "display div" only **data1 data3**;
**These are Dynamically Created div**

```
<div class="div1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1"><div class="data">data1</div></div>
<div class="div1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1"><div class="data">data2</div></div>
<div class="div1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1"><div class="data">data3</div></div>
```

**This is Display div**

```
<input type="submit" id="btndisplay" value="Display Data">
<div class="div-Display"></div>
```

Comment: So you want to show a div only when a checkbox is checked? You can do that with CSS. `.checkbox:checked + .data { display: block}` and  `.checkbox:not(:checked) + .data { display: none}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#btndisplay').click(function() {
    
    var clone = $('.div1 input[type=checkbox]:checked').siblings('.data').clone();
    $('.div-Display').empty().append(clone);
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1"><div class="data">data1</div></div>
<div class="div1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1"><div class="data">data2</div></div>
<div class="div1"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" value="1"><div class="data">data3</div></div>


<input type="submit" id="btndisplay" value="Display Data">
<div class="div-Display"></div>
```

Comment: var clone = $('.div1 input[type=checkbox]:checked').siblings('.data').html();
$('.div-Display').append(clone); 
is it work?

Comment: Yes that is working fine for me. Let me know if that works for you too. You need to put that within click handler of `#btndisplay`

Comment: i did it but it is taking only first div html not the next one what ever i checked

Comment: yes this is correct it is woring on clone() but when i am using html then it is not working. have look on link
https://jsfiddle.net/s8wtLroz/

Comment: [In an HTML document, `.html()` can be used to get the contents of any element. If the selector expression matches more than one element, only the first match will have its HTML content returned](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: so in this case what we can do.

Comment: yes i got the solution if i use **text()** then its woking fine as i want.

Comment: see what i did https://jsfiddle.net/s8wtLroz/3/ as you have given me new idea it is soloved my complete problem. thanks. @Adnan

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
$(".div-Display").append("<div class=\"div1\"><input type=\"checkbox\" class=\"checkbox\" value=\"1\" checked=true><div class=\"data\">data1</div></div>")
```

Keep point is to use `checked` attribute.

Comment: there is multiple div if i checked on checkbox. for example there are three div so i checked first div and third div so on the button click i have to show in "display div" only **data1 data3**;

Comment: So, your problem statement is :
Whenever you select the checkbox and then click on the "display" button, the data corresponding to selected checkbox should be visible. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [:checked Selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to (Hide or Show)[http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp] the divs... on the other side to be able to refer to the correct div, you have to give them a proper and unique `<div id=""...` or call them in the same order as the check boxes... if you create the checkboxes dynamically also, do it in pairs (checkbox - div) so you can relate them in order... well is just an idea...

You also may need to use `$(document).on("event","element",function(){...});` to refer to them because they are dynamically inserted in the DOM.